# Is there a way to UPDATE files in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there a way to update files for google app engine. I deployed the google app engine. I want to update the files on the google cloud app engine but I am unsure how to do this. When I am following the django google app engine.

How I try to fix this problem is by "re-deploying " but I receive a "too many files error" I am unsure how to fix this. How do I change the source code in the google app engine with the correct code?

Comment: Hello, can you check if you are reaching the [qutoas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas)? The maximum is 10000 files. If yes then you can contact Google Cloud Support in order to increase the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You update the files on App Engine by doing this command in your project root

```
gcloud app deploy .  --version YOUR_VERSION_NAME --project YOUR_PROJECT_NAME
```

But it sounds like that's what you're trying to do but you're getting a "too many files error"

I think the limit is 10,000 files. There most likely is a rogue directory in your project root that is causing the problem.

In your `app.yaml` you can add a `skip_files` section for files that should not get uploaded to App Engine.

```
skip_files:
- ^\.git/.*
- ^node_modules/(.*/)?
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files